# Displays firstname alphabetically but if firstname starts with 'A' it displays at the end in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want this output..
O/P:

```
FirstName

Babalu
Bhavesh
Chandan
Deepa
Heena
Neha
Akshata
Ashish
```

What I have tried:

I tried this query in mysql . I want ans in mysql please can any one help me out.

```
select ename from emp order by ename ;
```

I want ename start with 'A' at the end and remaining in asc order 
How??

Comment: show us what u have tried...

Comment: I cannot believe that google couldn't answer this one! But 'A' is a bad example. What if it was 'B' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`.

**Query**

```
select ename from emp
order by case when ename like 'A%' then 2 else 1 end, ename;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/SSLG87942)**

Comment: Thanks!.I got custom order .

Comment: @AngadBansode : Please mark it as answer if this solves your problem.